# Use of twitter fabric for android

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

Currently, I am making an Android app in which I need to integrate the complete Twitter app.

I went through Fabric website where I got to know that using the plugin in my app I could integrate Twitter App functionalities very easily.

I want to know if someone has used it.
 
Will it be really helpful in my case?
Does it give the same feel of the original Twitter app?
Does the plugin also provide UI(Twitter app UI) or do I have to make my own UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The twitter APIs and SDK is one of the most advanced and interesting ones i have ever used. It gives the real feel and look of twitter ( login, twitter lists). The SDK does most of the work for you. For example when you want to list tweets using List,the only thing you will need is to create a list view and a text view in your xml.

Initializing the sdk in your app is just less than 5 lines of code.

The console is easy to use as well. This will help you set up your app so fast.

For me i didnt feel like a programmer when using the SDK unlike when I am really struggling to use GMAIL APIs.

Go ahead and just do it.

Happy Coding.